# setuptool and setup.cfg : how declare data_files?

Tags: setuptools

The new approach to setup a Python package is to use a `setup.cfg` file.
But, it's impossible to find how I can add a `data_files` parameters.

How I can do it?

Comment: Do you mean like the [package_data](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html?highlight=package_data%20#data-files-support) of `setup.py`?

Comment: I think `data_files` is deprecated see [#2832](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/history.html?highlight=data_files#id118) and the link at GitHub.

Comment: Don't use `data_files` as they will almost always not work the way you expect them to. Use `package_data` instead.

Comment: As others have already said, `data_files` is deprecated (recommended against), `package_data` should be used instead. And note also that the "most newest" way now is to [declare the _setuptools_ configuration in `pyproject.toml`](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/pyproject_config.html), not in `setup.cfg`.

Comment: @sinoroc true, but [in the same document](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/pyproject_config.html#setuptools-specific-configuration) see the note: *"Support for declaring configurations not standardized by PEP 621 (i.e. the [tool.setuptools] table), is still in beta stage and might change in future releases."*.

Answer (score -1):

Use `package_data` instead of `data_files`.  For example if you wanted all the xml files in `mypkg/templates`, this would work in `setup.cfg`:

```
[options.package_data]
mypkg/templates =
  *.xml
```

See also: [Data Files Support](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html#package-data)